# HighCharts Bullet Chart display data label of the target

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label, target, bullet

I use Highchart bullet module to create a multiple bullet chart (horizontal or vertical).
An example of a chart here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/n5wjaf2e/

I can add datalabels for the main measure value with the following option :

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {           
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                inside: true
            },
```

but I want to display the label of the main measure AND the label of the target but there is no option to add the datalabel of the target measure (orange tick measure on my jsfiddle).

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `dataLabels` config as an array of objects, which means that more than one `dataLabel` can be added, next use the `dataLabels.formatter` callback to return the target value.

```
  dataLabels: [{
    enabled: true,
    inside: true
  }, {
    enabled: true,
    formatter() {
        //console.log(this)
        return this.point.target
    }
}],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2fxL03gz/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: Thanks for that, it's very usefull but I have another request on that, I would like the values diplsyed on top of the target line. In this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/kfyd6chr/ I'd like the orange values near the orange lines. Is it possible to use the value of the target to define the y position of the label ?

Comment: @vegaelce check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n9s743hr/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#translate

Comment: Thanks very much, it's exactly what I want. It remains only one thing, I'de like exactly the same behaviour when the chart is inverted. I tried to adapt the load event function without success https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/Lf1ka8us/. I cannot get the correct BBox().x of the target... Can you help me on that please ?

Comment: Try this config in this case: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0yba8cmL/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels